# How to Make a Polygon/shapefile which corresponds to the outer boundary of the given points?

Tags: python, arcgis, shapes, geopandas, shapely

i have a dataframe which contains X and Y cordinates of the points

df=

```
80.4    30  17.11755
80.1    30  17.11755
80.7    30  17.11755
80.7    30.3    17.11755
80.4    30.3    17.11755
80.1    30.3    17.11755
81.3    30  17.11755
81  30  17.11755
81  30.3    17.11755
81.3    30.3    17.11755
81.6    30  17.11755
81.6    30.3    17.11755
81.9    30.3    17.11755
81.9    30  17.11755
82.2    29.7    17.11755
81  29.7    17.11755
81.3    29.7    17.11755
81.6    29.7    17.11755
81.9    29.7    17.11755
82.2    30  17.11755
82.2    30.3    17.11755
80.7    29.7    17.11755
80.4    29.7    17.11755
80.1    29.7    17.11755
```

which can be represented like given below
[image]

How to make a shapefile/polygon which corresponds to the rectangle in the picture(ie, outer boundary of the cluster of points) if such points are given?

NB: points do make random shapes

Any help?

Comment: so you always want a box shape?  thats a much easier problem than an enveloping polygon

Comment: nope!! it will get more complex.. I am looking for more generalized solution

Comment: start by looking up "convex hull" :)

Answer (score 3):

you can use the shapely library for this

```
from __future__ import print_function # py2
from shapely.geometry import MultiPoint

if __name__=="__main__":
    pts = MultiPoint([(16,3), (12,17), (0,6), (-4,-6), (16,6), (16,-7), (16,-3), (17,-4), (5,19), (19,-8), (3,16), (12,13), (3,-4), (17,5), (-3,15), (-3,-9), (0,11), (-9,-3), (-4,-2), (12,10)])
    print (pts.convex_hull)
```

(I just stole this from https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Convex_hull#Python )

Answer (score 3):

To add to the correct answer above:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import MultiPoint, Polygon

pts = [[80.4,    30,  17.11755],
 [80.1,    30,  17.11755],
[80.7,    29.7,  17.11755]]

mp = MultiPoint(pts)

conv_hull = mp.convex_hull

poly = Polygon(conv_hull)

df = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': gpd.GeoSeries(poly)})
df.crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'} #Or whatever crs you want
df.to_file('poly.shp')
```